# oracle trigger delete after insert

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have a table "person"

```
id groupId occupation state
1  5       DIRECTOR   RETIREMENT
2  5       TEACHER    VACATION
3  4       DIRECTOR   ACTIVE
```

I need a trigger that delete new inserted row if it has the same grupiId, the same occupation and **state ACTIVE .**
For example:
If I insert a row with groupId 4, function Teacher, state wherever - it's OK.
If I insert a row with groupId 4, function Director, state HOLIDAY- it's OK.
But If I insert a row with groupId 4, function Director, state ACTIVE it should be deleted after insertion

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a trigger for this.  Just use a unique constraint or index:

```
alter table person add constraint unq_person_groupid_function
    unique (groupid, function);
```

As a note:  `function` is a poor choice for a column name, because it is a SQL keyword.

Comment: No, but you can emulate a filtered index if that is what you really need.